# Stretch background image to full width of the window even if the image dimensions are less than the page?

Tags: html, css, background-image

Is it possible to increase the size of a background image beyond it's dimensions to fill the page. I know there will be some blurring but that is OK.

For example if my image is 1000px wide how can I make it stretch beyond its width to fill the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
background-size: 100%
```

or

```
background-size: cover
```

Here is a common implementation.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x150');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I would essential like to figure out a way to combine both of those properties. background-size: cover stops the image at it's true width. background-size: 100% does not necessarily fill the whole height of the div.

Comment: `background-size:cover` stretches the image to the width of its container if the container is larger than the image.

Comment: Updated answer with runnable example.

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as background, and use the `background-size`, `background-position`, and `background-repeat` property:

```
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover;`

```css
#content { 
  
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background: #ddd url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nightlife/) no-repeat center center; 

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```